Cron job providing a specific line in my error log file
I have a bash script that uses ping testing for internet access, that has a cron job initiating the script with a 2>&1 output of any issues.
However, I need those issues, to write a specific line in the log file that I'm using.  No route to host and cannot resolve host do get captured, but that would indicate an issue getting to internet services and as such, should be logged in my log file.
I am really struggling to find a solution.
*/1 * * * * /onlineCHECK/onlineCHECK.sh >> /onlineCHECK/logs/onlineCHECK_issues--Crontab.log 2>&1

What I would like is it to write the following to my logfile:
(date "+%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")"|0|0|0|0|"(date "+%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")


You can group commands with { cmd1; cmd2; ...; } >> file.lof 2>&1. Would that be enough for your use case?

Why do you need the date at the beginning and end of the line?

@Fravadona That would only log the date before the script starts. I think they want the date on every line.

@Barmar That's what I was inquiring, in a roundabout way ^^

I have another script that takes the logfile and injects into a db that is then feed into PowerBI for futher analysis.  I was able to tweak it to my needs, now to take my internet down and test!  ;D

Pipe your command to a loop that prefixes each line with the date. Create another script date_prefix.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    echo "$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")|$line"
done

In crontab:
*/1 * * * * /onlineCHECK/onlineCHECK.sh 2>&1 | date_prefix >> /onlineCHECK/logs/onlineCHECK_issues--Crontab.log 2>&1


This is awesome, thank you so very much.  I'll try it out tonight!
